# How to do information architecture of a UGC based website/app?

Tags: website-design, navigation, information-architecture, redesign

What's the best possible way to make a user-generated website classify its content into categories or topics or tags to make the content searchable and discoverable?

How does one start redesigning the information architecture of an existing website?

Comment: This question needs more contextual description for it to be answered. When words like 'the best possible way' are used, it is given that 'one size will not fit all' and therefore whatever answers will always be contextual.

Answer (score 0):

This question is hard to answer without additional information about the purpose or what you/the user wants to achieve.

But if we take twitter or instagram as an example for user generated content, then hashtags are nothing different than labels. This is a well known and flexible system.

If the categories/labels are predefined, then i would propose to make suggestions for the generated content. Suggestions could be based on the text the user wrote or the user searches for tags and gets synonym or suggestion labels based on the search-term.